# Toggle generated table and images with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I tried to make a function which would accept a number when called, and hide any loop generated elements on page with the ID of #sub + the number provided.

```
<script>
    function toggleryhma($id) {
        $("#sub"+$id).toggle();
        $("#ryhmanum"+$id).toggle();
    }
</script>
```

The element I'd need to click to call the function is...

```
<span class=ryhmaspan onclick="$(toggleryhma('<?php echo $ryhmanum;?>');">
```

For some reason this doesn't seem to do anything. I basically have lots of images with the ID's "#sub1", "#sub2", "#sub3", etc...

Same with the #ryhmanum. I want to use those ID's to only toggle the items under the span I'm clicking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `onclick`. Your `onclick` should be like below.

```
onclick="toggleryhma('<?php echo $ryhmanum;?>')"
```

Comment: Thank you! Stupid mistake, but I'm not that familiar with jQuery. :)